# SQLAlchemy Class Decoration for __mapper_args__

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, polymorphism

I have a lot of classes which are part of polymorphism with my DB schema.
With most of them I (need to) do:

```
__mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': unique_integer}
# unique_integer is a unique integer different for each class ex: 10
```

Instead of this, I'd like to use a decorator, ie.:

```
@polid(10)
class ClassName(Inherited):
    # instead of repeating for each class the following:
    # __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 10}
    # I would like to have above decorator or something to do the trick.
    pass
```

How can I do this? What kind of decorator do I need to use? The following does not work (does not register):

```
def polid(v):
    def x(f):
        f.__mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': v}
        return f
    return x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a bit better, less magical solution attained so far could be:

```
def PID(value):
    ''' Mixin Class Generator For Polymorphic Identity Inheritance '''
    class MixinClassForPolymorphicIdentityInheritance: 
        __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': value}
    return MixinClassForPolymorphicIdentityInheritance
```

Usage:

```
class InheritingClass(PID(pidv), Parent): pass
```

(unfortunately)

Answer (score 2):

Use a [mixin](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/declarative.html#mixin-and-custom-base-classes).  Normally they're kind of a nightmare, but injecting common state into a declarative class seems like a reasonable use.

```
class PolyMixin(object):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 10}

class SomeTable(Base, PolyMixin):
    __tablename__ = "something"

class SomeOtherTable(Base, PolyMixin):
    __tablename__ = "something_else"
```

Comment: I am already using mixin. My question here is not really about them. I don't want to repeat **__mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 10}** but instead use a @decorator.

Comment: you don't have to repeat it.  just have each of the classes inherit from the mixin.  a decorator may not be reliable because by the time the decorator is called, the declarative magic is already done and the mapper already exists.

Comment: Eevee, thank you again for explaining however I think I'm failing to explain my self. ;-) I have about 100 classes, each with that __mapper_args__ .. line, with a different value. **10** is just an example. All 100 classes have 100 different values and therefore 100 lines of **__mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 1..100}**. You are absolutely right, a decorator does not work because magic has already happened. So I am seeking a more elegant way than 100 lines of **__mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 10}**. What do you think?

Comment: oh, i see.  in that case i'd just put the `__mapper_args__` in each class  :)  you have two options: add a dict containing a number to each class, or figure out some kind of insane magic and then add a decorator containing a number to each class.  i don't think the decorator really saves you anything here.

Answer (score 1):

Your decorator doesn't work because it tries to modify the class after it's been constructed, and at that point the mapper has already been set up.

```
def polid(value):
    return type("mixinclass", (object,), {"__mapper_args__": {'polymorphic_identity': value}})

class ClassName(polid(10), Inherited):
    pass
```

This creates a brand new class every time polid is called, with whatever custom mapper args you require.

Comment: there are some problems complex enough that dynamic class creation is useful.  trying to avoid attribute assignment is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is wrong with metaclass approach?

```
class PolyMeta(DeclarativeMeta):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, namespace, value=None, **kwargs):
        if value is not None:
            namespace['__mapper_args__'] = dict(polymorphic_identity=value)
        return super().__new__(cls, clsname, bases, namespace, **kwargs)

class Inherited(Base, metaclass=PolyMeta): ...

class ClassName(Inherited, value=10): ...
```

Of course, in Py2 you'll have to find some other way to signal information to the metaclass, but that's the price to pay for using a legacy language. :-P It shouldn't be so hard though: use a special attribute `_value`, or have an external dict mapping class names to values, or even make a fictional "base" remembering the value so you could write

```
class ClassName(Inherited, Value(10)): ...
```

In fact, I think that last approach is the best (if you're still stuck on Py2). If you need help with it, ask and I'll try to write it out.