# How can I set Polymorphic Identity after a class is defined?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I have a Class defining a table with Mapper Argument: `polymorphic_on: column`

I have some other Classes inhering this class and they all need to set `__mapper_args__ 'polymorphic_identity'`, which I would like to do after a class is defined instead of having it set within the Class definition.

How can I set polymorphic_identity Mapper Argument after a class is defined?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is not totally public API but should work:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper
mapper = class_mapper(MySubClass)
mapper.polymorphic_identity = "some_identity"
mapper.polymorphic_map["some_identity"] = mapper
# in 0.8, might try to fix this for 0.9
mapper._identity_class = mapper.inherits._identity_class
```

this is something that can be supported as a feature so feel free to [add a feature request](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/newticket).

Edit: here's a test using declarative:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper

Base= declarative_base()


class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String)
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": type, "polymorphic_identity": "a"}

class B(A):
    pass

mapper = class_mapper(B)
mapper.polymorphic_identity = "b"
mapper.polymorphic_map["b"] = mapper

e = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(e)

s = Session(e)

s.add_all([A(), B(), B(), A(), A()])
s.commit()

s.close()

assert [obj.type for obj in s.query(B).order_by(A.id)] \
            == ['b', 'b']

assert [type(obj) for obj in s.query(B).order_by(A.id)] \
            == [B, B]

assert [obj.type for obj in s.query(A).order_by(A.id)] \
            == ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a']
```

Comment: Hi @zzzeek! I've been wishing utterly for you to see this question. Thank you! Unfortunately, I do not thin this code block is all that's needed to do the trick. Can you please check question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102031/sqlalchemy-class-decoration-for-mapper-args/ for bit more details on the matter if you have the chance? Thanks again!

Comment: if you're using a class decorator then the class is already defined, and `__mapper_args__` won't have any effect.  The recipe above should still work.

Comment: Hi @zzzeek, as I tried to say, it unfortunately does not work. Thank you though for taking your time to help.

Comment: see attached demonstration.

Comment: Hi @zzzeek. That does seem to work in this case. I wonder what was wrong with my attempt. I'll check again, albeit solving the issue another way. Thank you once again.

Comment: Did anyone already fill a feature request for this, as you suggested?

Comment: Not yet? https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/2792