# SQLAlchemy: Merge() object with polymorphic relationship from session fails

Tags: python, testing, sqlalchemy, polymorphism

I'm currently writing tests in my application, which makes use of SQLAlchemy.

I have `tasks` belonging to `plans`.  But the `tasks` are polymorphic on a foreign key to a `type` table.  See: [How can I set Polymorphic Identity after a class is defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112340/how-can-i-set-polymorphic-identity-after-a-class-is-defined)

Basically, depending on the foreign key to `Type`, `Task` can be a `TaskA` object or a `TaskB` object, both subclassed from `Task` and by default an instance is a `Task` (with its own `type` attached).

In my tests `BaseTestCas`e, I initialize a session in `setUp` (and close it in `tearDown`).

When I try:

```
self.task.plan = self.plan
self.session.add_all([self.plan, self.task])
self.task = self.session.merge(self.task)
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py:154: SAWarning: Flushing object <Task at 0x5b93150> with incompatible polymorphic identity '58dbb417-1cb3-47c8-8bb4-5a7e2fe34498'; the object may not refresh and/or load correctly mapper._validate_polymorphic_identity(mapper, state, dict_)
```

Followed by an error stating

```
IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) null value in column "plan_id" violates not-null constraint
```

even though I assigned it a `plan` properly.

Any help will be appreciated.

(I'm unsure what other pieces of information are important for this.)